# error in data retieving sqlserver table

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, grid

```
my sql table data is 

column names & their datatypes are

column name           Datatype

installation_id        int(primarykey,identity(1,1))
Assignto               varchar 
customer_address       "
customer_contactno     "
package_details        "

1    ISP    N.G.O Colony    9841612124  Extended for 6 mnths
2    FE K.K Nagar   9865015695  expired
55  ISP02   aa          1234567890      aa
56  ISP02   asdf            0987654321      expired
57  ISP01   asdf        8907654321      Extended for 6 mnths
58  FE01    asdf        6789054321      expired
59  ISP02   asdf            5432109999      expired
60  DTo1    asdf            9999999999      expired
```

i want to group the column data based on assignto column.but am getting error?

my query is

select * from tn group by Assignto

Comment: What result you want to expect?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen to the other columns returned in your query? Each column must either be specified in the GROUP BY clause or included in an aggregate function such as COUNT, SUM or MAX

Answer (score 0):

You can't group by *. The return values must be in the grouping or be an aggregate.

```
Select AssignTo, Count(*) From tn Group by assignto
```